# Win server connection with SQL server. pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error')

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I tried the below code to connect to SQL Server from Windows 10 and it ran successfully but now I'm trying to run the same code from Windows Server 2016 and it's giving me SSL error. The code:

```
    conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=server_name;'
                            'Database=db_name;'
                            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Exception it's throwing now is

> pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error')

I tried searching various solutions to this issue but I don't have access to password and username. The ODBC driver name on both, the server and my machine is `SQL Server` only. Still, connection is refused in case of server.

I'm unable to understand this. Can anybody suggest me a way to execute it successfully from the server? I tried pyodbc but getting same error.

Comment: Can you try using the newer "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"?

Comment: I was hoping if few changes here and there in code would resolve the issue. In the end if nothing works, I will  install ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and will update here if it works.

Comment: Every fix online points to using a newer driver.

Comment: @GordThompson, upgrading to new driver worked.